# Trying to use jekyll-paginate-v2 and jekyll-multiple-language-plugin together

Tags: ruby, pagination, internationalization, jekyll

Well, I'm actually trying to create a multilingual website with Jekyll. Recently, I discovered this jekyll plugin called [jekyll-multiple-languages-plugin](https://github.com/Anthony-Gaudino/jekyll-multiple-languages-plugin) and well, my pagination went weird... So I preferred to update it to this maintained version called [jekyll-paginate-v2](https://github.com/sverrirs/jekyll-paginate-v2).

Already somebody has the same question as me, how could I make the paginator multilingual, so him/her created this issue on Github:

> Hey,
>
> couldn't find something in the old issues, so my question is: Is it somehow possible to set something like this in the config of jekyll?
>
> `permalink : "/:lang/page/:num/"` - **:lang** is the variable I need to create different versions of the same files.
>
> And I guess to obtain the posts I would need something like this:
>
> `{% for post in paginator.lang.posts %}`
>   instead of
>   `{% for post in paginator.posts %}`
>
> Would be great!!! I hope my problem is understandable.. or maybe you guys have a different approach?
>
> cheers,
>   bg

From: https://github.com/sverrirs/jekyll-paginate-v2/issues/17#issue-213207745

And kindly, @sverrirs replied to him/her with [this nice answer](https://github.com/sverrirs/jekyll-paginate-v2/issues/17#issuecomment-291592869). Which I'm carefully following. But I think that I found a wall...

Simply, I think that both plugins are incompatible:

> Well, I will need to reopen this. Because actually, I'm using your plugin with the ["Jekyll Multiple Languages Plugin"](https://github.com/Anthony-Gaudino/jekyll-multiple-languages-plugin)... And I'm having some troubles trying to follow what @sverrirs said on [this comment](https://github.com/sverrirs/jekyll-paginate-v2/issues/17#issuecomment-291592869)...
>
> I have the following structure for posts:
>
> [image: ...]
>
> And I already created two index.html in the root (one for the "en" lang and another for "es")... And then I created another two layouts...
>
> But when I debug the paginator (at myurl.com/en/, for example), the following appears:
>
> `{"per_page"=>5, "posts"=>[], "total_posts"=>0, "total_pages"=>1, "page"=>1, "page_path"=>"/index.html", "previous_page"=>nil, "previous_page_path"=>nil, "next_page"=>nil, "next_page_path"=>nil, "first_page"=>1, "first_page_path"=>"/index.html", "last_page"=>1, "last_page_path"=>"/en/1/index.html", "page_trail"=>nil}`
>
> Is like this plugin isn't compatible with the language one? Because, as you can see, there are some posts at my _i18n folder, but is like the locale isn't able to read them (because the `posts` property is empty)...
>
> What could I do?

From: https://github.com/sverrirs/jekyll-paginate-v2/issues/17#issuecomment-467270740

I said everything on that quote. But, navigating through the code of the plugin I can't found any reference (assigning) the posts variable... Or at least, see from where it's assigned...

https://github.com/sverrirs/jekyll-paginate-v2/blob/c657c5f8e02580a5e13f336d5c34fd4c81e212f7/lib/jekyll-paginate-v2/generator/paginationModel.rb

https://github.com/sverrirs/jekyll-paginate-v2/blob/7a15647777b12795515ffacbf3b9c09bc9b7f452/lib/jekyll-paginate-v2/generator/paginationIndexer.rb

The only things remarkable are `all_posts = self.get_docs_in_collections(template_config['collection'])` and `def self.index_posts_by(all_posts, index_key)`

But I can barely understand what is happening here, because I'm very newbie with Jekyll and Ruby...

Answer (score 0):

I've built a multilingual Jekyll website based on this how to:

[Making Jekyll  multilingual – Sylvain Durand](https://www.sylvaindurand.org/making-jekyll-multilingual/)

Here it is:

- Website: https://kamarada.github.io/
- Source: https://github.com/kamarada/kamarada-website (Jekyll) and https://github.com/kamarada/kamarada.github.io (compiled HTML)

To paginate it, I used the [jekyll-paginate-v2](https://github.com/sverrirs/jekyll-paginate-v2) plugin and filtered pages using locales.

Instructions on how to setup that plugin can be found here:

https://github.com/sverrirs/jekyll-paginate-v2/blob/master/README-GENERATOR.md

In this specific commit, you can see how I setup pagination:

https://github.com/kamarada/kamarada-website/commit/40fd718996e6c6756b915ffcac0b1be32df28e5d

In the future, I'm going to replace Sylvain Durand's `lang` with jekyll-paginate-v2's `locale`, so I don't use two front matter variables with the same purpose.

Please note that my website is not compatible with GitHub Pages, that's why I have separate repos for Jekyll source and compiled (and served) HTML.

The jekyll-paginate-v2 plugin is not supported by GitHub Pages: https://pages.github.com/versions/